# Retrofit: Android app fails SSL handshakes when launched on API21+ devices

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit, okhttp, handshake

I am building an App that fetches some `JSON` data via `HTTPS`, using Retrofit with a custom `OkHttp` client. It works fine on KitKat. Once I move to Android 5, 6 or 7, `SSL` handshakes fail.

The server supports `TLSv1` and nothing else. It also uses an ancient, expired, self-signed certificate. Tested it with the Qualys' SSL tool, which told me that all versions of Android should be able to connect. Here's what I've got:

## OkHttp client:

```
public class HTTPClient {

public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains

        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create a ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        //URL url = new URL(ApiIntentService.getHostAddress());
        //final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(url);

//            ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
//                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
//                    .cipherSuites(
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
//                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA)
//                    .build();

//            String hostname = "api.server.domain";
//            CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
//                    .add(hostname, "sha256/3Iiwgs3a0qjPCnBQzW/GeHhPbZvhaJtxKvMJJVO5KdU=")
//                    .build();

        final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
//            builder.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
//            builder.certificatePinner(certificatePinner);
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            builder.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                    String credential = Credentials.basic("user", "pass");
                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", credential)
                            .build();
                }
            });
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
        return okHttpClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I am aware how terribly butchered in terms of security this code is. My supervisor demanded it to be that way, and I informed him how bad this is.

I have tried 2 things to solve my problem, they're commented out in that piece of code - certificate pinning and requesting `TLSv1` specifically, with a list of ciphers. Found those two in other questions, but they changed nothing (stack trace is exactly the same).

## Stack trace

Here are the interesting bits of the stack trace:

```
I/RETROFIT: Data retrieval failed! javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
*snip*
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb43eb200: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0xac6fedd4:0x00000000)
                at       com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
```

It looks as if Android tries to use `SSLv3` all of a sudden, but Wireshark shows communication via `TLSv1`. It starts with `Client Hello`, as it should, but the server immediately answers with `Handshake Failure (40)`.

All help is greatly appreaciated, since I'm all out of ideas. Please ask for clarification if it's needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the commented out `ConnectionSpec` piece with `ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS` instead of `ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS`

Comment: Yes, I have. It was originally there, I changed it upon reading the documentation. No effect, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell your supervisor that your HTTP clients can’t connect to fatally insecure HTTPS servers. You can say it's a limitation of computers and your only option is to update the server.

Once you’ve done that you can add a development-only debug mode. To do it, enable a cipher suite that your server supports. You can get the list from the Qualys tool.

Comment: Got it working on a RPi-hosted test server (using TLSv1.2), tested on several devices with different versions of Android. It's obviously not an app-side problem. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4):

The solution for me was adding more ciphers as acceptable for OkHttpClient. Since API 21, some TLS certificates are deprecated for Android. This might help:

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new 
ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(      
CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,                    
CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
        .build();
```

For more info please visit: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: As far as I remember, I tried adding a lot of different ciphers and it just wouldn't work. Updating server software was the way to go.

Comment: @Daniil Yakovlev It does not work for me only on Android L. Works well on above versions. Any thoughts?